# python merge() : doesn't work if i change the dataframe order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I've been using `DataFrame_1.merge(DataFrame_2, blabla)` for a while. Now i come across a wired thing which i cann't figure out:

```py
final_df['com_name'] = final_df['com_name'].str.lower()
final_df.replace(blabla)
pipei_cus = pd.read_csv(blabla)

# it works
pipei_cus.merge(final_df, left_on='name', right_on='name_1', how='outer')

# not work if i change the order of DataFrame
final_df.merge(pipei_cus, left_on='name_1', right_on='name', how='outer')
```

what's more, if i save `final_df` to csv, then read it back, the code works!!

```py
final_df['com_name'] = final_df['com_name'].str.lower()
final_df.replace(blabla)
final_df.to_csv(blabla)

final_df = pd.read_csv(blabla)
pipei_cus = pd.read_csv(blabla)

# it works this time
final_df.merge(pipei_cus, left_on='name_1', right_on='name', how='outer')
```

thx a lot for any ideas!

Comment: You have two left_on , should it be right_on ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen That's a mistake, sorry. Now the code iss corrected: I never seen such a problem before. I'm using Pycharm 2019.1.1, Python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It highly likely is a bug from Pycharm, I ran the same code with a new version of Pycharm, i got the result which i want though no indication:

indication is here:

[image]

still no indication at all:

[image]